# Array strings in MIPS - an issue with a loop

Tags: arrays, string, mips

I am writing a code to display an array containing a number of Strings. Therefore I used a loop. However my counter doesn't work properly and I receive an error message and the first element (string) of an array. Could anybody help me, please?

```
'# $s0=count, $s1=total, $s3=data $s7=index

.data
```

Mssg1:      .asciiz "Hello\n"

Line1:      .asciiz "aab\n"

Line2:      .asciiz "ggdhj\n"

Line3:      .asciiz "uio\n"

array:      .word Line1, Line2, Line3

```
.globl main
.text
```

main:
    li $s1, 0       # total=0
    li $s0, 3       # count=3
    la $s7, array       # index

```
li $v0, 4       # print_str "Hello"
la $a0, Mssg1       
syscall
```

l1:
    lw $s3, 0($s7)      # data=sum[index]

```
add $s1, $s1, $s3   # total=total+data

addi $s7, $s7, 4    # increment
addi $s0, $s0, -1   # decrement

bne $s0, $0, l1     # if not equal 0 go back onto the loop 


add $t0, $0, $s0    # t0=s0

li $v0, 4
move $a0, $t0
lw $a0, array       # print_str 
syscall'
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of $t1 doesn't change in loop, so $t7 increases and you get the index of array that doesn't exist:

```
lw $t2,0($t7)    # data=array[index]
```

Comment: Ok, I've added decrement operation using s0 (previously t2 - sorry i've had 2 different versions of the same code and by accident I have inserted the less transparent one), but the effect is still the same. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Now your code doesn't define the content of the register $t7 before the string l1: lw $s3, 0($s7)  ...

Comment: Is it not enough that it's been declared as la $s7, array # index before it gets into the loop? Should I define it within the loop? So I am assuming that I should assign it to 0? Am I right?